# Non-mechanical load suggestions for a 12VDC / 6A PSU?

Tags: power-supply, electronic-load, electrical

I need to provide a load for the 12VDC/6A power supply. I used a small motor before, but something less mechanical (more reliable) like a light or (anything that's not mechanical) would be ideal.

Comment: How much of a load are you thinking?

Comment: Why do you need a load? Stability?

Answer (score 3):

The typical test load is a light bulb, or a power resistor, like a high wattage low resistance ceramic resistor. Just ensure proper heat sinking.

Comment: Would a 75W resistor work without overloading or killing the PSU (12VDC/6A)?

Comment: Wattage is only a part of the equation. W = I * R. I = V / R. If V is 12V, fill in the rest of the numbers.

Comment: W = I^2 * R, otherwise correct

Comment: @w5v0 ack. Meant W = I * V. Can You edit it?

Comment: we should understand why the Op needs to load it

Answer (score 1):

12 V car light bulbs should give you a selection of power ratings you can combine to give your 6 A load.

Comment: I really hope op isnt trying to load it all the way to 6 Amps.

Comment: That's fine, a common automotive brake light  1156 bulb is rated at 2.1 amps, so three of those will do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using electronic load?
If you change often the test load condition. 
I recommend the electronic load.

Below is related products of electronic load in google link.

http://www.tek.com/dc-electronic-load/series-2380

https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ifwxWcaXF4_z8wfdjJWADw&gws_rd=ssl#q=electronic+load&spf=1496448127996

Answer (score 0):

My normal go-to load is a filament light bulb, as many of the other answers have suggested.

However, there is a problem with testing power supplies with them, their cold (switch-on) resistance is usually more than an order of magntitude lower than their hot (running) resistance. This means that (for instance) a 50W 12v halogen bulb that takes ~4A running could easily draw 50A when cold.

Different power supplies react to overload in different ways. If it has a constant current mode, then the bulb will eventually heat up. If it trips, then it's a race between the bulb heating up and the over-current trip timer running out, it may be impossible to put the lamp directly onto the supply without tripping it. The same goes for starting a power supply with the lamp already connected, some supplies are smart enough to tell when they're being asked to start into a 'short circuit', and will refuse.

As bulbs are so convenient (high dissipation, self indicating, and while the world is switching over to LED, cheap, stock up on your filament lamp offers before they disappear!) it's worth finding some workarounds so they can be used.

a) Use multiple low power bulbs, and connect them one at a time, so the inrush for each is manageable.

b) Use a string of several high power bulbs in series (you did stock up on these things when I told you, didn't you?), and short them out one at a time so the inrush for each is manageable.